# What kotlin library to include to get AbstractKotlinInspection?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, intellij-plugin, code-inspection

I'm trying to write code inspection for Kotlin for IntelliJ IDEA. I need to use `AbstractKotlinInspection` which is from

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.inspections
```

The code is from https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/idea/idea-analysis/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/idea/inspections/AbstractKotlinInspection.kt

What library should I include (depend on in build.gradle) to get access to `AbstractKotlinInspection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just include the below in the `intellij` section of `build.gradle`

```
plugins 'kotlin'
```

e.g.

```
intellij {
    version '2018.1.4'
    pluginName 'ElyePlugin'
    plugins 'kotlin'
    updateSinceUntilBuild false
    alternativeIdePath "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/"
}
```

Comment: For [intellij-platform-plugin-template](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template) project , edit `gradle.properties` file, change **platformPlugins** to `platformPlugins = Kotlin,java`. My IDEA version is **IntelliJ IDEA 2020.2.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-202.6948.69.**